# How can I download a website and the links it references, but nothing more?

Tags: windows-10, internet, website

I have a list of links here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html

That I would liked all downloaded. Would anyone know how this would go?

Comment: What defines "nothing more"?

Comment: @random To me it seems strange to have this marked as a duplicate when the website in question **offers a zip file containing the needed pages** (see my answer). Why go for a general solution when there is a **specific solution** (which is **not** covered in the dupe) to the OP's question?

Comment: Either it's a duplicate of how to download a site and all the links but not all the links (because that's still not clarified) or it's out of scope for wanting to download a specific resource @dav

Answer (score 2):

You can download [Wget for Windows](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/) and use that from `cmd.exe`:

```
wget -r -l 2 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html
```

If you also want the images and CSS files for those pages, then add `-p` and also `-k` to change the links in the HTML so you can browse these pages offline.

[This tutorial](https://builtvisible.com/download-your-website-with-wget/) has some screenshots which may help.

The value of `-l 2` will get that first page, and all the pages that it links to.  You can increase the number to get deeper pages, but I fear it will follow some links away from the tutorials and around the Oracle website.

Alternatively you could try [VisualWget](https://sites.google.com/site/visualwget/a-download-manager-gui-based-on-wget-for-windows) which has a UI!

Alternatively you might like to download [the tutorials in ebook form](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java-tutorial-downloads-2005894.html).

Answer (score 1):

How can I download a website and the links it references

> I have a list of links here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html

Instead of downloading all the links in the "The Really Big Index" it is easier to just [Download the latest Java Tutorials bundle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java-tutorial-downloads-2005894.html).

It is available in a variety of formats - zip, epub and mobi.

`tutorial.zip` includes `reallybigindex.html` and all of the referenced files.

Here are the top level contents of the expanded zip file:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach this. Not knowing your desired end product I can't be very specific.

- [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), as suggested by @joeytwiddle
- [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) (similar to wget)
- google sheets
- browser add-ons for Chrome or Firefox (search *scraper*)

I'll expand on Google Sheets (I use this for simple one time projects):

- create a new sheet
- put this in cell a1 `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html`
- put this in cell b2 `=IMPORTXML(A1, "//a[@href]/text()")`*(this retrieves the text of the click)*
- put this in cell e2 `=IMPORTXML(A1, "//a[@href]/@href")`*(this retrieves the URL)*

The second parameter of the function is an **xpath** expression. You'll need to adjust those to get the result you want. There are many online xpath testers to help you do this.